# Samsung S7, Wifi keeps disconnecting

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, settings, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s7

I've searched around, and so I can ensure that this is not a duplicate.

- Smart Network Switch is off
- Keep Wifi on during sleep
- Wifi works excellent for other devices
- Wifi disconnects randomly even while the screen is open and device is in use

I opened up the Developer options, and turned on "Wi-Fi verbose logging" and when it disconnected, I saw these messages:

- NETWORK_SELECTION_PERMANENTLY_DISABLED
- NETWORK_SELECTION_DISABLED_BY_WIFI_MANAGER=2

Also in another occasion these:

- NETWORK_SELECTION_DISABLED_BY_ASSOCIATION_REJECTION=1
- NETWORK_SELECTION_DISABLED_BY_WIFI_MANAGER=1

The issue seems to be since installing an application, but I've uninstalled all recent applications on my phone, and it hasn't gotten better.

Safemode seemed to fix it, so there must be some kind of application interference, but the Wifi Control History only lists applications that turned on the wifi.

My only solution so far has been to disable wifi and re-enable it, or open up the wifi network manager in android, and tap the wifi connection. (presumably to override the 'network selection disabled')

---

Some logcat details:

```
[ 08-14 13:44:35.460  1364: 2509 E/WifiStateMachine ]
Did not find remoteAddress {10.100.5.1} in /proc/net/arp
```

and

```
I WifiHs20Service: Message received 5014
E WifiHs20Service: received HS20_UTILITY_ACTION_TYPE_HS20_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
D WifiStateMachine:  DisconnectedState !CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS uid=10225  rt=2982499/2982499 10225 0 num=40
D WifiStateMachine:  ConnectModeState !CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS uid=10225  rt=2982500/2982500 10225 0 num=40
D WifiStateMachine:  DisconnectedState !CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS uid=10225  rt=2982511/2982511 10225 0 num=40
D WifiStateMachine:  ConnectModeState !CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS uid=10225  rt=2982511/2982511 10225 0 num=40
```

When turnnig wifi back on, I sometimes see:

```
WifiStateMachine: There are no configured ssid
```

followed by many SSIDs of wifis I've already used. The SSID in range is not listed. Perhaps because the SSID in range is marked 'permanently disabled' (see above)

---

Additional Edit, more info:

- I'm unable to reliably replicate this. It only disconnects when I'm assuming it'll work, and it doesn't seem to be crashing while I'm trying to use it.
- I got a disconnect while doing a beyondpod (podcast app) update: https://pastebin.com/Edx7ADXZ Things to note:

  - I could not duplicate it with just the podcast app
  - If you search in the log for beyondpod, you'll see more information about where the disconnect happens. Sometime before: "08-23 12:53:46.600"

---

Update 3:

I wiped my phone, and it was fine for a while, but it came back. The same error codes: `NETWORK_SELECTION_PERMANENTLY_DISABLED` and `NETWORK_SELECTION_DISABLED_BY_WIFI_MANAGER=2`

I guess wiping it was not sufficient.

Is there anything I can run to constantly reset my wifi (when the hardware switch is on) to effectively cancel out whatever is turning it off?

Comment: I noticed this post, so I'm going to try and get adb logs to see if that provides more info: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143720/nexus-7-keeps-disconnecting-from-wi-fi

Comment: This seems relevant?: https://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/wifi-turn-on-and-off-in-loop-android-601-on-sm-g900f-where-can-i-submit-a-bug/201/299651?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~

Comment: I'm finding strings here that match my logcat, but I haven't narrowed down the logs to anything meaningful, and I'm hesitant to just dump all kinds of personal data: https://gist.github.com/czyzm/6a49abc9b5b0c0eb28d5999cccee0c77

Comment: If you are looking into logcat than you should look for specific time if you know when disconnection occured maybe something is there. How device works with other WiFi networks?

Comment: Do you know someplace I can upload ~2MB logs? pastebin.com doesn't work with a free trial. 2MB of logs is what I get when I try to cut it back to only one minute...

Comment: >Since I don't have enough reputation to comment ill have to post here. Hi Isaaclw, I see that the problem started when you installed an application, What was that application? You can take `"adb shell logcat"` contains wpa_supplicant related logs. Wpa_supplicant is an open source application which is used in android phones to connect and manage Wi-Fi connections.This would help your disconnect issue. or `"adb shell cat /proc/kmsg"` which is the file where kernel dumps the logs. Here you can see Wi-Fi crash related logs.

Comment: `adb shell cat /proc/kmsg` responds with permission denied

Comment: The other comment has the same problem as the logcat above. I dont have anyplace to upload the full logs

Comment: Debugging is so painful, partly because the error comes and goes and is unreliable. I wrote a script that helps debugging: https://pastebin.com/3rkNFaXC
And now the error isn't happening anymore. Go figure. I think due to my schedule I'm reformatting this weekend.
UGH.

Comment: Another edit. I wiped my phone, and it came back. I wish I didn't have so much going on this week and could actually solve it. Is there a place I can export my application list that would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android didn't indicate which applications where toggling the wifi status accurately, and the logs were unhelpful.

I later noticed that "[MyCricket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mizmowireless.acctmgt&hl=en_US)", an application that helps pay for my Phone Service, had a setting titled: [Turning on Cricket Wi-Fi Manager](https://www.cricketwireless.com/support/apps-and-services/wi-fi-manager/customer/wi-fi-manager.html)

Turning off this setting fixed it. I wish the Android controls had been more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings/display/screen saver & enable it. It seems to keep the wifi running. Hope I can help. I know it is an old thread but people still use this phone & this search is #2 on googling "s7 wifi keeps disconnecting" I hope I can help people like me.