# getting an old Nexus 7 to connect to wifi

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, nexus-7, nexus

I have an old 2012 Asus Nexus 7. How can I get it to connect to wifi again?

My goal is to use it as a digital photo frame, where the software for showing the slideshow of photos is a React app (website) that I've built.

So all I need this tablet to be able to do is browse a website hosted on my LAN.

(Ideally the browser ideally will support localStorage and IndexedDB.)

Currently, I can't get the Nexus 7 to connect to my wifi.

It has some custom limited version of Android 7.1.2 that I barely remember installing.

Sometimes it can see my wifi networks and lets me enter its password, but then never lets me browse the internet. Sometimes the wifi is "Off", and when I try to turn it "On", it just hangs.

My WiFi router is a NOKIA BGW320-505 (AT&T fiber) with WPA-2, WPA-3, and B/G/N/AX.

NOKIA BGW320-505 gives me 3 options in the dropdown for WPA Version: "WPA-1 and WPA-2", "WPA-2", "WPA-2 and WPA-3". It has been on "WPA-2 and WPA-3", and I'd love to keep it there. I temporarily changed it to WPA-2, and even then the Nexus won't connect.

I've already tried a factory reset of the Nexus.

What are my options for solving this? I'd be up for installing a new OS on the Nexus if there is a high chance of achieving my goal.

Comment: I installed 5.1.1 (LMY47V) and still had the same problem trying to connect to my router. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253173/getting-an-old-nexus-7-to-connect-to-wifi/253178#comment343147_253178 It would accept the password but never fully connect. It is able to connect to my Pixel 3 hotspot though.

Answer (score -1):

**Follow these steps to set up a fixed IP address on your Nexus 7:**

1. Make sure that the Wi-Fi on your Nexus 7 is turned on.
2. Go to your Nexus 7's Wi-Fi options.
3. Find your Wi-Fi network and choose it.
4. Click **"Forget"** to remove the network.
5. Join your Wi-Fi network again. You'll see a button that says **"Show advanced options"** Click on it.
6. Choose **"Static IP"** from the dropdown options or fields that appear next.
7. Enter a fixed IP address in the same area as your router's **DHCP server**. This means selecting an IP address that falls within your router's DHCP address pool.
8. Fill in the other essential information, such as Subnet Mask, Gateway, and DNS (if needed), which should match how your router is set up.
9. **Save** your settings.

> ***Alternatively***, if you want to set up a static IP address, you should
> do this instead of using DHCP, which automatically assigns the address
> from the router. Ensure the static IP address you choose is within the
> range of IP addresses allocated by the DHCP server in your router.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I tried it, and that status flickers between "Connecting" and "Saved", but it never seems to fully connect.

Comment: I might try: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/143794/22600 "nakasi" for Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi) 5.1.1 (LMY47V) https://developers.google.com/android/images#nakasi